# Android ListView within a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I want to create multiple listviews within my custom layout. I have given the layout an ID: `@+id/listview` which I want to attach and call as a `ListView`layout. I am calling it using `R.id.listview` within the `MobileArrayAdapter.java` file. There are no errors in the file but still not able to compile it. It gives a fatal exception. Basically, I want to import data from an excel-file into multiple list views embedded within relative layouts. Can someone please provide any examples or help me with removing the run time error for this code! Thanks...

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/kollege_name"
        android:width="170dp" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/grade_value"
        android:width="120dp" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/code_value" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/your_fit"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stream_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/stream_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />       


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/your_fit_image"
            android:layout_width="17sp"
            android:layout_height="17sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stream_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

main java file:

```
    package org.in.pappu;

import org.in.pappu.adaptor.MobileArrayAdapter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Details_Kollege extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] streams_list = new String[] { "EXTC", "IT", "COMP", "MECH", "INST"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter (this, streams_list));
    }

/*
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
        return true;
    }
    */
}
```

MobileArrayAdapter java

```
package org.in.pappu.adaptor;

import org.in.pappu.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.id.listview, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.id.listview, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stream_name);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.your_fit_image);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("EXTC")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }  else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use ```R.layout.``` resources to pass into ```LayoutInflater```.

Comment: you can get the ListView and setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the view using `setContentView()` in `Details_Kollege - onCreate()`  What is the exception that you get in Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in `oncreate()`

```
ListView ls=getListView();
setContentView(ls);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
public static class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.id.listview, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
                holder.textView = (TextView) rel.findViewById(R.id.stream_name);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) rel.findViewById(R.id.your_fit_image);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(values[position]);

            // Change icon based on name
            String s = values[position];

            System.out.println(s);

            if (s.equals("EXTC")) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }  else {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
            ImageView imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.length;
        }
    }
```